# CoR vs simple if else and matrix based functional calls where the chain is request dependent

Tags: c++, design-patterns, chain-of-responsibility

[image: Scenario]

I have used Handlers mapping along with if else conditional construct to handle chains which are request dependent.

```
Request r(TYPE1, ACTIVE);
std::vector<TYPE, STATUS> mapping;
mapping[TYPE1][PENDING] = myHandlerA();
// ... and so on
mapping[r.type()][r.status()]();

void myHandlerA(Request& r) {
  if(condition4(r))
  Handler4(r);

  else if(condition5(r))
  Handler5(r);

  else if(condition6(r))
  Handler6(r);

  else if(condition7(r))
  Handler7()
}
```

1. How do I do it using CoR when the chain is dependent on the request ? Is my approach a good design ?
2. Is this case applicable to CoR ? Can someone provide a snippet, if yes.
3. How does one identify applicability of CoR vs a simple mapping based coupled with if else ?

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier to answer seeing CoR handler interface:

```
class BaseHandler {
public:
    void setNext(BaseHandler* next){ m_next = next; }
    void handle(Request r){
        handleImpl(r);
        if(m_next!=nullptr) {
            m_next->handle(r);
        }
    };
    virtual ~BaseHandler(){ if (m_next) delete m_next; }
protected:
    BaseHandler* m_next;
    virtual void handleImpl(Request r) = 0;
};
```

*(Changed order of answers for more logical output)*

2. Your myHandlerA consists of multiple if-else statements, so just one of Handler4-Handler7 is used.

 
CoR is dedicated rather to perform multiple handlers in concrete order.

1. *(First read description, then go to snippets)*
You can create factory method to produce you handler suitable for your request.

```
class Request {
    public:
    int type;
};

class Handler1: public BaseHandler{
    void handleImpl (Request r) override {
        cout << "Handler1" << endl;
    }
};

class Handler2: public BaseHandler{
    void handleImpl (Request r) override {
        cout << "Handler2" << endl;
    }
};

class MyFactory {
public:
    BaseHandler* getHandler(const Request& r){
        if (r.type==1){
            return new Handler1;
        }
        if (r.type==2){
            return new Handler2;
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    Request r;
    r.type=1;
    MyFactory myFactory;
    BaseHandler* handler = myFactory.getHandler(r);
    handler->handle(r);
    delete handler;
}
```

OR 

You can create CoR handler (see above) that sets its m_next to proper handler depending on request type.
That way you may apply CoR in your solution.

```
class RequestTypeHandler: public BaseHandler{
    void handleImpl (Request r) override {
        cout << "RequestTypeHandler" << endl;
        if (r.type==1){
            cout << "Select Handler1" << endl;
            m_next = new Handler1;
        }
        if (r.type==2){
            cout << "Select Handler2" << endl;
            m_next = new Handler2;
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    Request r;
    r.type=1;
    RequestTypeHandler handler;
    handler.handle(r);
}
```

3. As said in answer for 1., CoR is dedicated rather to order of handlers, not just one, like in case of mapping.

Also, I'd suggest great page with Design Patterns: https://refactoring.guru

Comment: 1. Why would one create a handler for every new request that comes up ? It just carries a functional logic. Moreover if else (instead of mapping type) would take `O(size/2)` rather than `O(1)` ? 2.  Why would one create the chain inside `handleImpl` ? We would want to resolve such dependencies at compile time only. 3. My use case is a complex case of mapping + CoR.. Am I correct to assume it is best handled using if else, without CoR...

Comment: You can always create one instance and use it multiple times, depends on factory design you need, specifically you may return singleton, or keep returned objects inside factory.
 And to answer computational complexity question: you are right, using map in MyFactory::getHandler or in RequestTypeHandler::handleImpl makes it more efficient.
I'll update my answer later.

Comment: 2. Maybe just typed request and overloading you need, if the types upfront, you know:
`template <Type type, Status status> class TypedRequest {};`
`template <Type type, Status status> void TypedHandler(TypedRequest<type, status>) {}`
`void typedHandler(TypedRequest<type1, active>) {cout<<"TypedHandler<type1, active>()"<<endl;}`
`void typedHandler(TypedRequest<type2, active>) {cout<<"TypedHandler<type2, active>()"<<endl;}`
3.Mapping+CoR in question I do not see ( by CoR, what do you mean?). Also, in myHandlerA itself place for CoR in my understanding, I do not see.

Comment: 2. It is not feasible to change the Request type or also create TypedRequest from it, in a code base. ... 3. Mapping + CoR : Yes, I meant that myHandlerA requires CoR somewhat while mapping case does not, which makes me question the applicability of CoR. Both cases have a logic to get the handler, but in one it is known by simple indexing, while in another it is kind of `if else` sequenced through uncoupled  handlers. So, the applicability is more when we wish to keep the handlers independent and also having condition of when to handle inside handlers and not client code..

Comment: RequestType is not constexpr, can we use it in templates as non type template paramater ?

Comment: Unfortunately, non-constexpr variable as template parameter to use, possible is not.